# How to extract the values from dictionary with condition

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary

I need to extract the mobile phone number from a a list of dictionaries using a regex.

Need to extract only from the d[num]

The dictionary:

```
d = [{'name': 'a', 'num': '9134567890','num2':'912311111'},
    {'name': 'd', 'num': '9134567890','num2':'5151'},
    {'name': 'b', 'num': '0134567890','num2':'51'},
    {'name': 'c', 'num': '9034567890','num2':'12'},
    {'name': 'm', 'num': '9034590','num2':'13'}
    ]
```

1. The phone number is the value for key `"num"` for each dictionary.
2. All phone numbers must contain 10 digits.
3. If the phone number starts with `91`, it is `'local'`.
4. If the phone number starts with `01`, it is `'global'`.
5. If the phone number starts with anything else, it is `'others'`.

The pseudo-code:

```
s = {'locals':[], 'global':[], 'others':[]}
for i in d:
    for k,v in i.items():
        #if num starts with 91:
           #append locals
        #elif num starts with 01:
           #append to globals
        #else:
            #append to others
```

Pseudo Code

```
for i in my_dict_1:
    print ([ v for k,v in i.items() if str(v).startswith('91') if i['num']])
```

My Expected output:

```
{'locals':[a,d], 'global':['b'], 'others':['d']}
```

Since question become hold I have solved question

```
s = {'locals':[], 'global':[],'others':[]}
for i in d:
    if i['num'].startswith('91'):
        s['locals'].append(i['num'])
    elif i['num'].startswith('01'):
        s['global'].append(i['num'])
    else:
        s['others'].append(i['num'])
s
```

Out

```
{'global': ['0134567890'],
 'locals': ['9134567890', '9134567890'],
 'others': ['9034567890', '9034590']}
```

Comment: I am not clear on why it has been put on hold. Although it was not well worded, possibly due to language limitations (the original post has since been edited), I do believe it did have enough detail for adequate answer to be provided. And it was not asking multiple questions. Rather it was posing multiple conditions on one question.

Comment: You're almost there. Just remove the second `for` loop and replace the first `if` statement with 
    `if i[num].startswith('91'):
        s['locals'].append(i[num])`
The others will be similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression with alternations and a `defaultdict` as in:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

d = [
    {'name': 'a', 'num': '9134567890','num2':'912311111'},
    {'name': 'd', 'num': '9134567890','num2':'5151'},
    {'name': 'b', 'num': '0134567890','num2':'51'},
    {'name': 'c', 'num': '9034567890','num2':'12'},
    {'name': 'm', 'num': '9034590','num2':'13'}
]

# regular expression
rx = re.compile(r'^(?=\d{10}$)(?P<local>91.+)|(?P<global>01.+)|(?P<others>.+)')

# output dict
output = defaultdict(list)

# list comprehension
_ = [output[key].append(m[key])
     for item in d
     for m in [rx.search(item["num"])] if m
     for key in m.groupdict() if m[key]]

print(output)
```

This yields

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'local': ['9134567890', '9134567890'], 'global': ['0134567890'], 'others': ['9034567890', '9034590']})
```

---

The regular expression makes sure there are exactly 10 digits (that's what the positive lookahead does) and then puts the different matches into the according groups. Afterwards we check which dict has been filled in a big comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

@Jan

I'm still new to regex in Python. Shouldn't the number '9034590' be excluded in 'others' because it does not contain ten digits? How will you fix the `^(?=\d{10}$)` part of your rx?

I changed that line to (admittedly not the best fix, but it still works)

```
rx = re.compile(r'(?P<local>91\d{8})|(?P<global>01\d{8})|(?P<others>\d{10})')
```

This yields

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'local': ['9134567890', '9134567890'], 'global': ['0134567890'], 'others': ['9034567890']})
```

as asked by the poster.

Edit:
I figured it out (the better fix), @Jan you were missing the parentheses for the three **or** expressions.

```
rx = re.compile(r'^(?=\d{10}$)((?P<local>91\d+)|(?P<global>01\d+)|(?P<others>\d+))')
```